# Synchronization around variables as opposed to classes or methods

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, design-patterns, synchronization

In my scenario, the user sends a request to the server and then the server can upload a list of items to the database. The list of items is uploaded to the database in a for loop, consisting of several queries. It is very important that these items are added to the database in a sequential 
order.

Now, the problem is that if the user issues another request, another set of for loops will be launched, and the items may not be added to the database in the correct order. (Because there will be two for loops adding items to the database).

Example : Request 1: 1,2,3
          Request 2: 4,5,6
Order in which they are inserted into the database:
Should be : 1,2,3,4,5,6
However, potentially can be :1,4,2,5,6,3

If a different user issues a request, there is no problem, because the two requests will then be mutually exclusive.

To solve the problem, I could use a static method or use the synchronized keyword, but I do not want to cause a bottleneck in the code(other users should not have to wait to access the database!).

Or, perhaps it is a bad idea to perform multiple queries using a for loop?

How can I synchronize my code around a "request" rather than an object or method? Is there a design pattern or something?

Comment: What would be the problem if the items in two lists are inserted in a *different* order? AFAIK it would be easier if each group of items in a list will have a unique index based on time (or controlled by the database) as unique identifier of the group of data processed in the current transaction.

Comment: Your case is like a bank. I can give a teller multiple deposits and withdrawals in one visit to the window. They get done in order. So can someone else. There is no interference. But if my wife and I both visit at the same time and her withdrawal falls after my small withdrawal and before my large deposit, we can get an overdrawn situation. (It's not a perfect analogy. Ok.)

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is the potential for inteference. In my case, I give my deposits to the cashier after you, but another cashier works on my checks. So, some of my deposits may get done before some of yours.

Answer (score 2):

You should enforce the transaction in your database. No matter what in-process synchronization you do, the moment you have more than one application server instance (which is the case in almost all non-trivial applications), your code would break.

You could e.g. use an exclusive row lock on the row that represents the user. This way, the requests will be serialized at the database and it doesn't matter how many application server you have.

Comment: If all the database activity for one user request is done in one transaction, even though there is a loop with many database queries, a second request by the user won't interfere and they will execute independently at the database level. Much better than doing it in the application container.

Comment: How can I make this occur in one transaction?

Comment: @AsasfpojElse: I guess I need a bit more detail to answer that. If you literally wanted to do what you want, you will need to use some kind of explicit locking (like a row lock on a user row). However, "order of insertion" itself is never a valid synchronization requirement (in the end, you don't care in what order something was done. You are just interested in what state is observable). If you tell me a bit more on what you are trying to do, I might be able to help.

Comment: Basically, the user inputs steps into a table. The step number is an auto increment primary key. I want the request that gets their the earliest to have each of their step numbers to be less than the the step numbers of the requests that get their later.

Comment: @AsasfpojElse: Ah ok. If you ask me, why not simply execute an insert statement every time the user submits a step, and display a confirmation that the step was committed on success? This way the user can make sure his/her intended ordering is respected. If the user chooses to submit a step while the earlier transaction is ongoing and that step gets registered first, that seems to me like a user's problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to make a `Queue` of requests to insert into the database.  That way all of the queries will be executed in the sequential form you need.

But, to do this correctly you will want to do this in a separate thread(a good thing to do regardless as Database transactions can often block, or be very slow).

This solution will not need "locks" and will still be responsive due to the threading, but will maintain your need for linearity.

Comment: This will cause users to wait on each others requests to complete unless there is effectively a queue for each user.

Comment: If there is a common queue, then this is not an issue.  All this approach does is guarantee sequential access to the db, while not locking users while the db is handled.

Comment: You will need to explain. Consider a queue (or line) at the grocery store. I would call that a common queue. Everyone is in the same line. Everybody waits on the guy in front to finish and on everyone in front of them. OP probably doesn't want that. Each user seems to be able to submit DB queries just fine if they in kept in order by user.

Comment: The Op wants sequential order.  So if person 1,2, and 3 all have requests, that whoever inserts it first gets handled, then second then third.  Having a common queue enforces this linearity.  Having that queue (and the db) be handled in a separate thread allows them to continue on with their business as soon as they submit their request.

Comment: Actually, the way I read it, OP is ok with concurrent requests from different users. Concurrent requests by the same user are the problem. Notice where OP says, "If a different user issues a request, there is no problem..." Well ... that's the way I understand it.

Comment: That is correct Lee; sorry, it's kind of difficult for me to explain.

Comment: Either way, the single queue guarantees that if the same user submits more than once, its still handled in a linear fashion

Answer (score 0):

If multiple application servers are not a problem, consider StripedLock.  It lets you synchronize on an ID, while creating only a bounded number of locks.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StripedExplained

```
private static Striped<Lock> STRIPPED_LOCK = Striped.lazyWeakLock(64);
try {
    STRIPPED_LOCK.get(id).lock();
    ....stuff....
} finally {
    STRIPPED_LOCK.get(id).unlock();
}
```

In your case you could use the session ID (string) for the Id.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a complete picture here, but since you say "the user issues another request", I gather that he does not wait for the first request to complete?

In that case, you could consider a "command" pattern; the query is represented in an object that is put in a queue, and the program processes things out of the queue one at a time.  Each object in the queue is a "command" that represents its processing.

Comment: I am using the command pattern actually. But, using the command pattern here like that doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution. Why is this? Because, I would have to keep a queue for every user and their actions. This doesn't seem elegant or all that readable.

Comment: Evidently the database content is tied to the user. That is, perhaps, why they don't interfere with each other. I add my multiple entries in order and you add yours and we don't conflict because they aren't related to each other. Only to you and me.

Comment: Can your command object contain user information, so that processing it does not have to use it from the user's context?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best, but if I am in your situation, I will do in separted in-queue process with separated batch.

Example: You has two table for queue and detail:

```
List_Queue(
    id int identity not null primary key,
    user_id varchar(xx),
    is_processable tinyint default 0,
    is_processing tinyint default 0,
    is_processed tinyint default 0,
)

List_Queue_Detail(
    queue_id int,
    // your rest of data,
    inserted_timestamp datetime
)
```

The `List_Queue` table will be inserted every time the user do submission. Then in your example, it may be has this kind of record in queue table:

```
11, user01, 0, 0
12, user01, 0, 0
```

Your transaction will insert to queue detail table. It may be on unsorted order like:

```
11, 1, '01.001'
11, 2, '01.021'
12, 4, '01.032'
12, 5, '01.044'
11, 3, '01.055'
12, 6, '01.061'
```

Please notice the timestamp in second and milisecond. You can have normal datetime here.

Now you have completed the insertion into queue detail table. assume you has this state of queue now:

```
11, user01, 0, 0, 0
12, user01, 1, 0, 0
```

Process 12 is completed earlier than 11. It is normal scenario. Now your batch (executed every minute maybe) will get the `smallest queue id with is_processed = 0', so you get:

```
11, user01, 0, 0, 0
```

And it does not processing the request. If it processable, then you can begin to insert the queue detail to real transaction table. Don't forget to mark the request as `is_processing` when begin insertion.